# Tinymce plugin images on opening plugin don't wrap to width of parent div

Tags: html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am working on a simple TinyMCE plugin which displays images which are populated from a big chunk of HTML.

The JS for the plugin is here:

https://emojinode.com/assets/includes/tinymce/plugins/twemoji_svg_nature/plugin.min.js

You can see that the HTML is defined in the line starting:

```
return a = "<div style='width:400px;'>...
```

When the plugin icon is clicked, the HTML is rendered, but for some reason the images don't wrap to the width of the parent 400px div.

This is the example page here:

https://emojinode.com/test.html

Click on the dog toolbar icon to see the issue.

Yet, if I view the HTML that is rendered on clicking the dog icon, the images do wrap fine.

The rendered HTML for that is shown at the bottom of the test page above, showing how the images wrap fine.

I wondered if there is any way I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skin of TinyMCE has CSS that it uses to manage the editor content and part of that is this CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

You can override that for your `div` elements with inline CSS or you can pass CSS to the editor via `content_css` that overrides this as well.  Note that you likely want to target your specific `div` elements or you may run into other issues by overriding that skin CSS.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added another test page (https://emojinode.com/test1.html). I found that the plugin takes no notice of CSS defined inside `content_css` but would sort of take notice if the CSS was defined inline within the plugin code. However, the images still don't wrap even after adding `white-space: normal !important; word-break:break-all !important;` to the inline CSS in the plugin. Do you think this might be a limitation of the way the plugin functionality in TinyMCE works? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I was wrong. I had forgotten to add a width to the main div, once I set that to 400px, problem solved, along with setting the white-space CSS. Thanks for your help @Michael Fromin!